# Why compiling a program produces a file that is not executable?

Tags: compilation, fortran

I am using **g95** to compile a fortran code. I use

```
C:\MinGW\bin>g95.exe -c C:\test\coil.f -o C:\test\coil.exe
```

It compiles and gives coil.exe which is created as 16 bit application so when ever I try to run this executable it throws an incompatibility error. I am using windows 7 64bit. I think by default it goes to 16 bit. Is there a way to get 64 bit in place of 16bit?

Comment: If you want to obtain an executable, compile it as follows: `g95.exe C:\test\coil.f -o C:\test\coil.exe`, i.e. without the `-c` switch. With `-c` you are getting an _object file_  (`.obj`) which is not supposed to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain an executable, compile it as follows:

```
g95.exe C:\test\coil.f -o C:\test\coil.exe
```

, i.e. without the `-c` switch. With `-c` you are getting an object file (`.obj`) which is not supposed to be executed.

From the comment by @DmitriChubarov